# update statement throw exception

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I wrote this query:

```
      Ado_All.Parameters.Clear;
      Ado_All.SQL.Clear;
      Ado_All.SQL.Add('update Tbl_Customer_Services set fk_Customer =:0, fk_Services =:1, Start_Date =:2, End_Date=:3');
      Ado_All.SQL.Add(' ,Hesab =:4, Domain_Name =:5,Comments =:7 where Customer_Services_Id =:6 ');       
      Ado_CmbNames.MoveBy(Cmb_Customer.ItemIndex);
      Ado_All.Parameters[0].Value := Ado_CmbNames.FieldByName('Customer_Id').AsString;
      Ado_All.Parameters[1].Value := '1';
      Ado_All.Parameters[2].Value := '10/10/2010';
      Ado_All.Parameters[3].Value := '10/10/2010';
      Ado_All.Parameters[4].Value :=Txt_Mali.Text;
      Ado_All.Parameters[5].Value := Txt_Domin.Text;
      Ado_All.Parameters[6].Value := ADOQuery2.FieldByName('Customer_Services_Id').AsString;
      Ado_All.Parameters[7].Value := Txt_Domin.Text;
      Ado_All.ExecSQL;
```

Ado_All is an AdoQuery. but it has following error:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the colon characters (`:`) in the SQL statement are causing the problem. Try simply using `= ?` as the placeholders for the parameter values in the SQL text, e.g.

```
UPDATE Tbl_Customer_services SET fk_Customer = ?, fk_Services = ?, ...
```

and be sure to add the parameter values to the `.Parameters` collection in the *exact* order that they appear in the SQL statement.